# Can we use different mode for decryption instead of using mode which is used in encryption?

Tags: encryption, aes, hmac, cbc, gcm

I am decrypting the Apple Payment Token in Demandware, the apple pay token is encrypted in GCM mode, but in Demandware, we don't have GCM mode in Cipher class, so can I use other modes for decryption? Can anyone suggest me regarding this?

Comment: If you don't care about authenticity of the token (you really should care about authenticity) you _could_ just CTR decrypt the data. Or you could use an external library (good solution) or implement GCM yourself (bad solution).

Comment: When I use CTR mode I am getting decoded value as "�i���^Z�z�t�*c�2���#,��
�bL�������7�ڱ����Y�S ���qhl��R�tP�'Y���b �j�C�`.ײz�]��". I am not sure where I am making mistake.

Comment: My code is: var cipher : Cipher = new Cipher();
            return cipher.decrypt(base64Data1, "ae0cca3b27726fe290268947531354d9", "AES/CTR/NoPadding", IV, 1);@SEJPM

Comment: You are not computing the correct IV. GCM takes the 12 byte nonce and appends a 4 byte counter. The first data block is encrypted with said counter having the value "1" and also note that the data may have the nonce prepended to the actual data.

Comment: Thanks for your information, But Apple Pay uses an initialization vector of 16 null bytes , var IV : Bytes = new Bytes("0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"); As per this link developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/PassKit/… @SEJPM

Comment: @user3064373 I would love to know if you were able to do this.  I'm also working with Demandware, but have attempted this with NPM as a suitable POC.

Comment: @MattHudson, I also did this using NPM, but was not able to do in Demandware as its does not have the necessary API  for decryption, So ended up with using Cybersource for Apple Pay Integration.

Comment: Can you send NPM version?  I was using this: https://github.com/sidimansourjs/applepay-token but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I also tried using the same link which you have used

Comment: I have spoken to creator, who made some suggestions.  Will post it if I get it working.

Comment: Got it working: https://github.com/inturbidus/applepay-token